# Unable to fetch return value from a method in Java

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to create a sidebar using values fetch from my servers.
But the values that I am trying to fetch from the method which holds the return value is causing error. I am unable to call this method.

Here's the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private String mActivityTitle;
    public String returnnumfromAsyncTask;
    private TextView setTextValue;
    private TextView textViewid;
    private Button buttonHit;
    private String var;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        mDrawerList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.navList);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mActivityTitle = getTitle().toString();


        addDrawerItems();
        setupDrawer();


        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        /*textViewid = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewid);
        buttonHit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonHit);

        buttonHit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new JSONTask().execute("http://xyz.co/tests/ems/query.php");
            }
        });*/

    }


    private void addDrawerItems() {
        new JSONTask().execute("http://xyz.co/tests/ems/query.php");

        JSONTask json = new JSONTask();
        String myArray = json.myMethod();


        String[] osArray = { "Android", "iOS", "Windows", "OS X", "Linux" };
        mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, osArray);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(mAdapter);


        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Time for an upgrade!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }



    private void setupDrawer() {
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {


            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Navigation!");
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }


            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mActivityTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };


        mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }


    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();


        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }


        // Activate the navigation drawer toggle
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }


        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public class JSONTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            HttpURLConnection connection = null;
            BufferedReader reader = null;

            try {
                URL url = new URL(params[0]);
                connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                connection.connect();
//                    connecting to the url

                //Reading the data in bytes stream
                InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
//Reading the data by creating a buffer
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                String line="";
                while((line = reader.readLine())!= null){
                    buffer.append(line);
                }

                String finalJson = buffer.toString();
                JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(finalJson);

                List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                JSONArray array = parentObject.getJSONArray("kitten");
                for(int i = 0 ; i < array.length() ; i++){
                    list.add(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("if")+"\n");
                }
               /*String finalObject = parentObject.getString("name");

                JSONArray parentArray = parentObject.getJSONArray("kitten");

                StringBuffer finalBufferedData = new StringBuffer();
                for(int i=0;i<parentArray.length();i++) {
                    JSONObject finalObject = parentArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    int curr = finalObject.getInt("name");
                    //int bus = finalObject.getInt("bus");

                    finalBufferedData.append(curr + "\n" );
                }*/

                //return finalBufferedData.toString();

                return list.toString();
//                    setting text view from the url
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally{
                if(connection !=null) {
                    connection.disconnect();
                }

                try {
                    if (reader != null)
                    {
                        reader.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            //textViewid.setText(result);
            myMethod(result);
        }

        public String myMethod(String result){
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Notice the line:

```
String myArray = json.myMethod();
```

It tries to call a function myMethod() which returns a string value or rather an array which I get by executing asynctask.

But somehow I am not able to call myMethod from JSON asynctask function.
So my primary question is how to call a method which returns a value and thereby use it in my code?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What should `myMethod()` do? Are you trying to return a String value from a void method() ? If so, it needs to be a callback.

Comment: @Shark myMethod basically tries to return a string or an array processed from my servers using AsyncTask. But when I try to call the method it's throwing errors.

Comment: Where do you use `myArray` value? I see that you only assign it from `myMethod()` return value. Also `myMethod()` always returns `null`.

Comment: @mixel I shall use in place of osArray which you can find in this statement  mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, osArray); which is a static array I used. But since I am not able to get myArray perfect. I have not replaced it.

Comment: @topsycoder You should more carefully prepare question and code samples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AsyncTask.doInBackground()` runs asynchronously.

You should run `JSONTask` like so:

```
private void addDrawerItems() {
    new JSONTask().execute("http://xyz.co/tests/ems/query.php");
}
```

And move code that uses result of this task to `JSONTask.onPostExecute()`:

```
public class JSONTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,String[]> {

    @Override
    protected String[] doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();
            //connecting to the url

            //Reading the data in bytes stream
            InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
            // Reading the data by creating a buffer
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            String line="";
            while((line = reader.readLine())!= null){
                buffer.append(line);
            }

            String finalJson = buffer.toString();
            JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(finalJson);

            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            JSONArray array = parentObject.getJSONArray("kitten");
            for(int i = 0 ; i < array.length() ; i++){
                list.add(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("if")+"\n");
            }
            return list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally{
            if(connection !=null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }

            try {
                if (reader != null)
                {
                    reader.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {
        mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, result);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                 Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Time for an upgrade!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }
        });

    }

}
```

Comment: I did that, but I have a question. In place of osArray I want to use the result. Which shall be a JSON array [{"if":"4000"},{"if":"4000"},{"if":"4000"},{"if":"4000"},{"if":"4000"}] like one. But when I try to replace it. It shows error cannot resolve constructor

Comment: `ArrayAdapter<String>` constructor accepts `String[]` (string array) as third parameter. So you have to parse your json to string array. Replace `list.toString()` with `list.toArray(new String[list.size()])` and change `JSONTask` third type parameter to `String[]`.

Comment: Still throwing errors, at list.toArray(new String [list.size()]). The error is incompatible types required string and found string[]

Comment: Because you did not change `JSONTask` third type parameter to `String[]` - 1. replace `AsyncTask<String,String,String>` with `AsyncTask<String,String,String[]>`. 2. change `doInBackground()` return type to `String[]`. 3. change `onPostExecute()` parameter type to `String[]`.

Comment: This is what you mean by changing onPostExecute() parameter?  protected void onPostExecute(String[] result). I changed it to string[] but still has this error of cannot resolve constructor in ArrayAdapter

Comment: Ahh.. Replace `this` with `MainActivity.this` in `ArrayAdapter` constructor. Also I updated answer with full code for `JSONTask`.

Comment: Thanks @mixel for the solution. It worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 1):

Because `doInBackground` method of `JSONTask` class executed in background Thread,so:

```
JSONTask json = new JSONTask();
String myArray = json.myMethod();
```

these lines are executing just after call of `execute` method.

EITHER

use `AsyncTask.get()` method which will freeze UI Thread until `doInBackground` method execution not completed.

OR

Best way is use `onPostExecute` for setting Adapter for ListView.

**EDIT :**

As question in comment:

> How do I use onPostExecute to sett adapter for ListView?

If `JSONTask` class is inner-class of `MainActivity` class then you can access all variables of `MainActivity` class in `JSONTask` directly.just move related code in  `onPostExecute` method.

and if `JSONTask` class is separate class then pass Activity Context to `JSONTask` for accessing UI elements from normal java class as:

**1.** Add a constructor to `JSONTask` class for getting Activity Context as:

```
private Context mContext;
private ListView mDrawerList;
JSONTask(Context mContext, ListView mDrawerList){
  this.mContext=mContext;
  this.mDrawerList=mDrawerList;
 }
```

**2.** Pass  `MainActivity.this` as parameter when creating object of `JSONTask` class:

```
  JSONTask objJSONTask=new JSONTask(MainActivity.this);
  objJSONTask.execute("http://xyz.co/tests/ems/query.php");
```

**3.** Now use `mContext` and mDrawerList to show ListView in `onPostExecute`

Comment: How do I use onPostExecute to sett adapter for ListView?

Comment: @topsycoder: `JSONTask ` class in inner class of `MainActivity ` class?

Comment: Why down-voter feels  shame in leaving comments for `Why they are down-voting`